# Excel solver replicates in R

Tags: r, excel, shiny, solver

I'm currently on a project using R/R shiny and I want to make my program faster...

Here we have the function that takes a lot of time :

```
fjeu=function(d){
        res <- sqrt(((A*cos(d)+sqrt(P3.GX.X^2+P3.GX.Y^2)*cos(atan2(P3.GX.X,P3.GX.Y)-asin(A*sin(d)/B)))-C3.GN.X)^2+((A*sin(d)+sqrt(P3.GX.X^2+P3.GX.Y^2)*sin(atan2(P3.GX.X,P3.GX.Y)-asin(A*sin(d)/B)))-C3.GN.Y)^2)-A
        return(res)
}
```

In this example, "n" is a sample number that can be between 100 and 1'000'000.
Between 100 and 1'000, no problem, the code is approximately fast, but when I try it with 100'000 or 1'000'000, it's very slow.

In my code, I call this function 360 times (using angles -> from 0 to 360).

The function comes from an excel file where I make this calculation and a solver thing, but the solver makes it faster.

This is the code where I call the function:

```
angles <- seq(0, 2*pi, by = (2*pi)/360)
matjeu <- t(matrix(rep(angles), nr=length(angles), nc=n))
exc_max <- apply(apply(matjeu, 2, fjeu), 1, max)
```

Please help me!

Comment: But `n` isn't used in your sample code...  Also, please consider using indentation and other formatting to help those less familiar with your code than you are.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot something, let me edit it